# In Python, how do I check the size of a StringIO object?

Tags: python

And get the bytes of that StringIO object?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`StringIO` objects implement the file API, so you can get their size in exactly the same way as you can with a `file` object: seek to the end and see where it goes.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import os
s = StringIO()
s.write("abc")
pos = s.tell()
s.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
print s.tell()
s.seek(pos)
```

As Kimvais mentions, you can also use the `len`, but note that that's specific to StringIO objects.  In general, a major reason to use these objects in the first place is to use them with code that expects a file-like object.  When you're dealing with a generic file-like object, you generally want to do the above to get its length, since that works with *any* file-like object.

Comment: I recommend storing the result of `pos = s.tell()` and `s.seek(pos)` after checking this value, in the case that file position is important to any of your consumers.

Answer (score 21):

By checking the **len** attribute and using the **getvalue()** method

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> s.write("foobar")
>>> s.len
6
>>> s.write(" and spameggs")
>>> s.len
19
>>> s.getvalue()
'foobar and spameggs'
```

Comment: I was going to call `tell()`, but yours is much more obviously correct.

Comment: I don't have that. Instead, I have this:  ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'flush', 'getvalue', 'isatty', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reset', 'seek', 'tell', 'truncate']

Comment: I'm guessing you're actually using `cStringIO` and not `StringIO`, which--for what reason I don't know--doesn't have a `len` property to match `StringIO`.  I guess the `len` property is actually undocumented, which is also a little odd.

Comment: Also note that the `len` was removed in Python3, so you cannot use your solution in Python3.

Comment: When on Python3, please note that `StringIO.write()` returns the amount of characters written, so you can just keep track of them without the need of checking the length...

Comment: This does not work in Python 3.5. `AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'len'`

Comment: what to use instead of len for StringIO?

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'getvalue' method and checked the length of the return value

```
len(s.getvalue())
```