# How to make tar backup using python

Tags: python, shell, backup

I have directory  /home/user1 , user2 .
I want to loop through all usernames home dir and then make the tar.gz file and then store it in /backups directory.

I am new to python so confused how to start

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os
import tarfile

home = '/home/'
backup_dir = '/backup/'

home_dirs = [ name for name in os.listdir(home) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(home, name)) ]

for directory in home_dirs:
    full_dir = os.path.join(home, directory)
    tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, directory+'.tar.gz'), 'w:gz')
    tar.add(full_dir)
    tar.close()
```

Comment: thanks buddy , i will try that , will it work if i have many subdirectories and files . i mean i want to have separate backups for `/home/user1.tar.gz , /home/user2.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

[python write string directly to tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740820/python-write-string-directly-to-tarfile)
and http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tar-examples

Comment: its not only string anmes but complete folders with 100s of files . how can i feed folder

Comment: use os.walk() to walk into the the related folder and adding each file individually.