# Python: Assign a compression level to tarfile

Tags: python, compression, tar

My question is a follow up to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849999/how-to-make-tar-backup-using-python).
I would like to know how I can modify the following code so that I can assign a compression level:

```
import os
import tarfile

home = '//global//scratch//chamar//parsed_data//batch0'
backup_dir = '//global//scratch//chamar//parsed_data//'

home_dirs = [ name for name in os.listdir(home) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(home, name)) ]

for directory in home_dirs:
    full_dir = os.path.join(home, directory)
    tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(backup_dir, directory+'.tar.gz'), 'w:gz')
    tar.add(full_dir, arcname=directory)
    tar.close()
```

Basically, what the code does is that I loop through each directory in `batch0` and compress each directory (where in each directory there are 6000+ files) and create a `tar.gz` compressed file for each directory in `//global//scratch//chamar//parsed_data//`. 
I think by default the compression level is = 9 but it takes a lot of time to compressed. I don't need a lot of compression. A level 5 would be enough. How can I modify the above code to include a compression level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a compresslevel option in the `gzopen` method. The line below should replace the one with the tarfile.open call in your example:

```
tar = tarfile.TarFile.gzopen(os.path.join(backup_dir, directory+'.tar.gz'), mode='w', compresslevel=5)
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I get the following error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gzopen'`

Comment: which version of python do you have?

Comment: 2.7.2 ... I am using it in a cluster at my university. Hopefully this version is ok for gzopen

Comment: Sorry, it should be `tarfile.TarFile.gzopen`. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `compresslevel` attribute you can pass to `open()` (no need to use `gzopen()` directly):

```
tar = tarfile.open(filename, "w:gz", compresslevel=5)
```

From the [gzip documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html), `compresslevel` can be a number between 1 and 9 (9 is the default), 1 being the fastest and least compressed, and 9 being the slowest and most compressed.

[**See also**: [tarfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)]