# Python tarfile slow than Linux command

Tags: python, centos

I tried the different way to zip folder.My understanding is that Python built-in module always faster than subprocess.call("Linux command").
But I just did some demo. The tarfile module is slow than  subprocess.call("tar").Can someone explain it to me?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time
import tarfile
import subprocess

tStart1 = time.time()

TestFolder = ["Jack", "Robin"]
for folder in TestFolder:
    name = "/mnt/ShareDrive/Share/ExistingUsers/"+folder
    path = "/mnt/TEST2/"
    tar = tarfile.open(path+folder+".tar.gz", "w:gz")
    tar.add(name)
    tar.close()
tEnd1 = time.time()

time.sleep(2)

tStart2 = time.time()
for folder in TestFolder:
    path = "/mnt/TEST1/"
    subprocess.call(["tar", "zcvf", path+folder+".tar.gz", "-P", "/mnt/ShareDrive/Share/ExistingUsers/"+folder])
tEnd2 = time.time()

print "The module cost %f sec" % (tEnd1 - tStart1)
print "The subprocess cost %f sec" % (tEnd2 - tStart2)
```

The tarfile module cost 63 sec. 
The subprocess cost only 32 sec.

The total size of two folders is 433 MB

Comment: 'My understanding is that Python built-in module always faster than subprocess.call("Linux command")'. There is no basis for that assumption.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tar` is written in C. The `tarfile` module is a pure Python implementation of tar handling. There is no way that the module will be faster than the command.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems like I have a big misunderstand for Python module. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, the gzip compression of `tarfile` module is implemented in C, so it has just as good performance as `tar czf`. It just has a different default compress level.

Answer (score 2):

`tarfile` with `w:gz` uses a default compression level of 9, whereas `tar cfz` uses a default compression level of 6. So while Python is indeed much slower, it also gives a better compression ratio. If you pass `tarfile.open(..., 'w:gz' compresslevel=6)`, then you get approximately the same performance as `tar cfz`.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think the compression level might be a big factor. According to the `tarfile.open` documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) the default level is 9 (the maximum) for `w:gz`, significantly higher (and slower) than the default for `tar czf` (level 6). I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308288/579925 to a different SO question helped me with modifying the compression level for `tarfile.open` .

Comment: Thanks, I clarified my answer accordingly