# Python created tar.gz file contains "_" folder, how to remove?

Tags: python

The .tar.gz files I'm created via Python contain a "_" root-level folder which I need to remove.

Here's the .tar.gz function I'm using:

```
def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname='')
```

I create the .tar.gz with:
make_tarfile('ARCHIVE.tar.gz', 'C:\FolderA')

[As you can see, there is a "_" folder added to the .tar.gz. Any suggestions on how I remove it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8egvr.png) Interestingly enough, when I extract the .tar.gz, the " _ " folder doesn't appear. In that sense, it's fine. But this would be a .tar.gz consumed by many users, so I'd like to have it not contain quirks like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the 7z interface is the `..` entry that it adds to every directory so that you can navigate up by clicking on it. It does not exist in the tar archive.

Consider the following:

```
def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        for name in os.listdir(source_dir):
            tar.add(os.path.join(source_dir, name), arcname=name)
```

When called as `make_tarfile('ARCHIVE.tar.gz', 'FolderA')` where `FolderA` is:

```
FolderA/
|-- FolderB
|   `-- example
`-- example
```

Results in an archive containing:

```
example
FolderB/
FolderB/example
```

Now I don't like this as I prefer my tar files to extract into a top level directory. As they were created with `tar -czf ARCHIVE.tar.gz FolderA/` and have the entries:

```
FolderA/
FolderA/example
FolderA/FolderB/
FolderA/FolderB/example
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The "_" folder wasn't a 7z interface issue, I could see it using other programs too. Using the 7z CLI was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this exact scenario--use 7Zip CLI and do a wildcard copy of all the contents of the desired folder (the parent folder will be omitted). Like this:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', 'a', '-ttar', 'C:\ARCHIVE.tar', 'C:\FolderA\*'])
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', 'a', '-tgzip', 'C:\ARCHIVE.tar.gz', 'C:\ARCHIVE.tar'])
```

No "_" folder will be in the archive either, it'll be nice and clean :)