# How can I programmatically create a tar archive of nested directories and files solely from Python strings and without temporary files?

Tags: python, file, tar, in-memory

I want to create a tar archive with a hierarchical directory structure from Python, using strings for the contents of the files.  I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740820/python-write-string-directly-to-tarfile) , which shows a way of adding strings as files, but not as directories.  How can I add directories on the fly to a tar archive without actually making them?

Something like:

```
archive.tgz:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    dir1/
        file3.txt
        dir2/
            file4.txt
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extending the example given in the question linked, you can do it as follows:

```
import tarfile
import StringIO
import time

tar = tarfile.TarFile("test.tar", "w")

string = StringIO.StringIO()
string.write("hello")
string.seek(0)

info = tarfile.TarInfo(name='dir')
info.type = tarfile.DIRTYPE
info.mode = 0755
info.mtime = time.time()
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info)

info = tarfile.TarInfo(name='dir/foo')
info.size=len(string.buf)
info.mtime = time.time()
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=string)

tar.close()
```

Be careful with `mode` attribute since default value might not include execute permissions for the owner of the directory which is needed to change to it and get its contents.

Comment: ... and you might want to set the `TarInfo.mtime` member to prevent GNU tar's `implausibly old time stamp` warning, but +1.

Comment: @larsmans You're right. I've updated my answer to set `TarInfo.mtime`. Thanks for your commetn.

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification to the helpful [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649029/3780389) so that it works with python 3 as well as python 2 (and matches the OP's example a bit closer):

```
from io import BytesIO
import tarfile
import time

# create and open empty tar file
tar = tarfile.open("test.tgz", "w:gz")

# Add a file
file1_contents = BytesIO("hello 1".encode())
finfo1 = tarfile.TarInfo(name='file1.txt')
finfo1.size = len(file1_contents.getvalue())
finfo1.mtime = time.time()
tar.addfile(tarinfo=finfo1, fileobj=file1_contents)

# create directory in the tar file
dinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name='dir')
dinfo.type = tarfile.DIRTYPE
dinfo.mode = 0o755
dinfo.mtime = time.time()
tar.addfile(tarinfo=dinfo)

# add a file to the new directory in the tar file
file2_contents = BytesIO("hello 2".encode())
finfo2 = tarfile.TarInfo(name='dir/file2.txt')
finfo2.size = len(file2_contents.getvalue())
finfo2.mtime = time.time()
tar.addfile(tarinfo=finfo2, fileobj=file2_contents)

tar.close()
```

In particular, I updated octal syntax following [PEP 3127 -- Integer Literal Support and Syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#id11), switched to `BytesIO from io`, used `getvalue` instead of `buf`, and used `open` instead of `TarFile` to show zipped output as in the example. (Context handler usage (`with ... as tar:`) would also work in both python2 and python3, but cut and paste didn't work with my python2 repl, so I didn't switch it.)  Tested on python 2.7.15+ and python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the tar file format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tar/corion.htm) it seems doable. The files that go in each subdirectory get the relative pathname (e.g. `dir1/file3.txt`) as their name.

The only trick is that you must define each directory before the files that go into it (`tar` won't create the necessary subdirectories on the fly). There is a special flag you can use to identify a tarfile entry as a directory, but for legacy purposes, `tar` also accepts file entries having names that end with `/` as representing directories, so you should be able to just add `dir1/` as a file from a zero-length string using the same technique.