# How does one add string to tarfile in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, stringio, tarfile

I have problem adding an `str` to a tar arhive in python. In python 2 I used such method:

```
fname = "archive_name"
params_src = "some arbitrarty string to be added to the archive"

params_sio = io.StringIO(params_src)
archive = tarfile.open(fname+".tgz", "w:gz")
tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name="params")
tarinfo.size = len(params_src)
archive.addfile(tarinfo, params_sio)
```

Its essentially the same what can be found in this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740820/python-write-string-directly-to-tarfile).
It worked well. However, going to python 3 it broke and results with the following error:

```
  File "./translate_report.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "./translate_report.py", line 48, in main
    archive.addfile(tarinfo, params_sio)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tarfile.py", line 2111, in addfile
    copyfileobj(fileobj, self.fileobj, tarinfo.size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tarfile.py", line 276, in copyfileobj
    dst.write(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/gzip.py", line 317, in write
    self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
  TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

To be honest I have trouble understanding where it comes from since I do not feed any `str` to `tarfile` module back to the point where I do construct `StringIO` object.
I know the meanings of `StringIO` and `str`, bytes and such changed a bit from python 2 to 3 but I do not see a mistake and cannot come up with better logic to solve this task.

I create `StringIO` object precisely to provide buffer methods around the string I want to add to the archive. Yet it strikes me that some `str` does not provide it. On top of it the exception is raised around lines that seem to be responsible for checksum calculations.

Can some one please explain what I am miss-understanding or at least give an example how to add a simple `str` to the tar archive with out creating an intermediate file on the file-system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing to a file, you need to encode your unicode data to bytes explicitly; `StringIO` objects do not do this for you, it's a *text* memory file. Use `io.BytesIO()` instead and encode:

```
params_sio = io.BytesIO(params_src.encode('utf8'))
```

Adjust your encoding to your data, of course.

Comment: It seems that I have been beating around good bushes but never got the right combination. It works. Thanks.