# saving string to tarfile in python 3 throws unexpected end of data error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, gzip, tar

I'm trying to open a tar.gz file full of json data, extract the text from them, and save them back to tar.gz.  Here's my code in Python 3 thus far.

```
from get_clean_text import get_cleaned_text # my own module
import tarfile
import os
import json
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path


def make_clean_gzip(inzip):
    outzip = "extracted/clean-" + inzip
    with tarfile.open(inzip, 'r:gz') as infile, tarfile.open(outzip, 'w:gz') as outfile:
        jfiles = infile.getnames()
        for j in jfiles:
            dirtycase = json.loads(infile.extractfile(j).read().decode("utf-8"))
            cleaned = get_cleaned_text(dirtycase)
            newtarfile = tarfile.TarInfo(Path(j).stem + ".txt")
            fobj = StringIO()
            fobj.write(cleaned)
            newtarfile.size = fobj.tell()
            outfile.addfile(newtarfile, fobj)
```

However, this throws an `OSError: unexpected end of data`.  (I've verified, incidentally, that all the strings I want to write are of non-zero length, and also verified that calling `tell()` on the file object returns the same value as calling `len()` on the string.)

I found [this prior SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988973/how-does-one-add-string-to-tarfile-in-python3), which suggested that the problem is that StringIO isn't encoded, so I swapped out BytesIO for StringIO and then `fobj.write(cleaned.encode("utf-8"))`, but this still throws the same error.

I also tried simply not setting the size on the TarInfo object, and that code ran, but created an archive with a bunch of empty files.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.addfile()` method presumably just calls `.read()` on the file object you give it - which returns nothing in this case, because you're *already at the end of the file*.  Try adding `fobj.seek(0)` just before that line.

Comment: OMG.  *palm to forehead* I seriously just spent an hour trying to debug this and it was actually that simple.  Thanks, friend.

Comment: Timesaver! Had a similar issue right now with xml.dom.minidom.parse(file).