# Write data directly to a tar archive

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, tar, jsonpickle

I am looking for a way in which I can pickle some Python objects into a combined tar archive. Further I also need to use `np.save(....)` to save some numpy arrays in yet the same archive. Of corse, I also need to read them later.

So what I tried is

```
a = np.linspace(1,10,10000)    
tar = tarfile.open(fileName, "w")
tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo.frombuf(np.save(a, fileName))
tar.close()
```

and I get the error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Simlar problems I get if I pickle an object in the tar-file. Any suggestions? If it is easier, json-pickle would also work.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments I confused the arguments of np.save(). However, this does not solve the issue, as now I get the error:

```
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

EDIT 2: If there is no solution to the above problem, do you know of any other way of time efficiently boundle files?

Comment: For one thing, the arguments to [`np.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) are the wrong way around. The first one needs to be either an open file object or a string, but you're giving it `a`, which is an `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks! I editted the question

Comment: `np.save` returns `None`.

Comment: Okay, that basically means, there is no way to get it done?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to write "directly" to a `tar` file, although you could certainly save the array to an intermediate file, then add this to the archive (i.e. using `tar.add()`).

Comment: Saving the files is the week point, as it really consumes a lot of time...then I would even have to do it twice :(

Comment: [`np.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) can be used to save multiple numpy arrays within a single zipped archive. It will also accept arbitrary Python objects, which will be cast to arrays of dtype `np.object` and therefore pickled.

Comment: that sounds very promissing ... I will have a look into that! Thanks!

Comment: If I do that with an object of a complex class and subsequently load it, it is no longer of the type of the former class.

Comment: Yes, it will be an array of dtype `np.object` that contains your class instance. Try accessing the first element of the array.

Comment: This is the string "arr_0" ;)

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Could you edit your question to show the actual object you are trying to store?

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm not a expert `tar` user, but I can point out a couple of things:

```
 a = np.linspace(1,10,10000)    

 tar = tarfile.open(fileName, "w")
```

If you want to add a file to an existing file, use the "a" mode (or study the available modes).  "w" creates a new blank file:

```
 tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo.frombuf(np.save(a, fileName))
```

The correct use of `np.save` has already been mentioned.

A `TarInfo` object is not the file/data, but rather information about the file.  That information is placed in the tar file before the data, in a 512 byte buffer.  `tobuf` creates such a buffer from the attributes of the object.  `frombuf` decodes such a buffer.  It is used, for example in the `fromtarfile` method:

```
def fromtarfile(cls, tarfile):
    """Return the next TarInfo object from TarFile object
       tarfile.
    """
    buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    obj = cls.frombuf(buf, tarfile.encoding, tarfile.errors)
    obj.offset = tarfile.fileobj.tell() - BLOCKSIZE
    return obj._proc_member(tarfile)
```

So clearly `frombuf` is not what you want to use here.

A 2009 SO question - 
[python write string directly to tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740820/python-write-string-directly-to-tarfile)
-  shows that it is possible to write directly to a tarfile by using a string buffer.  From the accepted answer:

```
# create a `StringIO` object, and fill it
string = StringIO.StringIO()
...
# create `TarInfo` object:
info = tarfile.TarInfo(name="foo")
info.size=len(string.buf)
# use both with `addfile`:
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=string)
```

I think you can do a `np.save` to `StringIO` buffer, but I'd have to check/test to be sure.  For ordinary arrays, `save` writes a header with size, shape, dtype info, and then adds the array's data buffer.  For other objects and array it resorts to `pickle`.

I'd suggest getting a regular `np.save` to file, followed by `addfile` working.  Then see if writing to a string buffer works and whether it saves any time.

---

Here's a test script.  It writes one array to a tar file, closes and reopens the file and writes another, and finally it extracts the files and loads them.  Returned shapes look fine.  I haven't looked at whether it is possible to extract these files to memory buffers or not.

`np.savez` could do the same thing zip archiving (rather than tar).

```
import numpy as np
import tarfile

import io   # python3 version
abuf = io.BytesIO()

np.save(abuf, np.arange(100))
abuf.seek(0)

tar=tarfile.TarFile('test.tar','w')
info= tarfile.TarInfo(name='anArray')
info.size=len(abuf.getbuffer())
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=abuf)
tar.close()

abuf = io.BytesIO()
np.save(abuf, np.ones((2,3,4)))
abuf.seek(0)

tar=tarfile.TarFile('test.tar','a')
info= tarfile.TarInfo(name='anOther')
info.size=len(abuf.getbuffer())
tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=abuf)
tar.close()

tar=tarfile.TarFile('test.tar','r')
print(tar.getnames())
tar.extractall()
# can I extract to buffers?
tar.close()
a=np.load('anArray')
b=np.load('anOther')
print(a.shape, b.shape)
```

also

```
1415:~/mypy$ tar -tvf test.tar 
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             480 1969-12-31 16:00 anArray 
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             272 1969-12-31 16:00 anOther
```